# I want to create a second environment for Jupyterlab Desktop but fail

Tags: environment, jupyter-lab, desktop

For a start, I have tried environments created with  both python venv and conda.  With the conda environments I have successfully created new kernels for use in Jupyterlab Desktop, so I can do some things right!

My version of Jupyterlab is 4.0.5

example conda environment:

```
conda create -n aaaa python=3.11 ipykernel
conda activate aaaa
jlab
```

In the titlebar of jlab there is a button with "jlab_server". Click on the button and there is an option to Browse for Python path on your computer. I choose the path

```
/home/user/conda3/envs/aaaa/bin/python3
```

and jlab then responds with Invalid Environment.

What am I doing wrong, and what more should I be doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install jupyterlab in the environment, not only ipykernel. It should be:

```
conda create -n aaaa python=3.11 ipykernel jupyterlab
```

Comment: I thought that was not required for jupyterlab desktop. I better check again.

Comment: There used to be a time when only jupyter server was required, but as of now full jupyterlab needs to be installed in the environment which is documented here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/blob/master/troubleshoot.md#dealing-with-custom-environment-server-launch-errors. Feel welcome to leave feedback on GitHub.

Comment: All is now OK. The installation of juopyterlab into the aaaa environment now allows jupyterlab desktop to swap environments.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Steps for use in conda envs:
(1) create a conda env by     conda create -n JNB001 python=3.11 ;
(2) Do not install python. You did that in step 1; you need to install jupyterlab and additional packages you are going to use via conda or pip. If needed, search for code in google by anaconda::jupyterlab or mathplot..;
(3) if you need additional packages, install those afterwards; search how to via anaconda::package-name;
(4) In the jupyterlab browser, open a new python-notebook and store that;
(5) get access to open.ai or ChatGPT and ask for sample codes.

Steps in Jupyterlab Desktop are slightly different.
Find instructions at YouTube, look for your OS.

I use VSCode and always open VE, and open that env in VSCode. That way I can  view and install if needed the needed packages. In the notebook you will can open them, only if installed!